# How I can access web cam in Mac build using maccatalist?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mac-catalyst

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewCam: UIView!
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?


captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.low
    
    // Get all audio and video devices on this machine
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
    
    // Find the FaceTime HD camera object
    for device in devices {
        print(device)
        
        if ((device as AnyObject).hasMediaType(AVMediaType.video)) {
            print(device)
            captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
        }
    }
    
    if captureDevice != nil {
        
        do {
            try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!))
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            previewLayer?.frame = (self.viewCam.frame)
            
            // Add previewLayer into custom view
            self.viewCam.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
            
            // Start camera
            
        } catch {
            print(AVCaptureSessionErrorKey.description)
        }
    }
```

I am using this code in Mac-catalist (iOS) and it works fine for iPhone iPad but its returning **captureDevice** nil on Mac.

But when I used same code in Mac native build it worked fine. I am not sure how to achieve this in Mac-catalist.

Please answer below or make comments, thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not how to run `AVCaptureSession`.  Show the entire lines of code.

Comment: @ElTomato This is the whole code I have used but it worked in native OSX development.